# How to check serial port in linux work properly

Tags: c++, linux, serialization, ubuntu-10.04

I am going to use serial port in my C++ program linux ubuntu 10.4 ,this is my open port function :

```
    int Recorder::OpenPort()
    {
     int intFd ;
    struct termios options;   

    intFd=open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY| O_NDELAY);
    if (intFd==-1){
        perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyS0 - ");
    }
    fcntl(intFd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);    /*configuration the port*/ 

    tcgetattr(intFd, &options);

    //set baud rates at 115200 
    cfsetispeed(&options, B115200 );                
    cfsetospeed(&options, B115200);

    //mask the character size to 8 bit data  & no parity.CHARACTER SIZE SETTING
    options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;        
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    options.c_cflag |=  CS8;

    //setting hardware flow control
    options.c_cflag |= CRTSCTS;    

    //Enable the receiver and set local mode .should always be enabled (enable receiver and dont change owner of port)
    options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);

    //flush output buffer
    options.c_lflag |= FLUSHO;

    //choosing raw data disable echoing 
    options.c_lflag &=  ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);

    //not setting software  flow control
    options.c_iflag &=  ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); 


    options.c_oflag &=  ~OPOST; 

//  //output changes :for mapping NL to CR-NL. 

    //  options.c_oflag |= (OPOST | ONLCR );        
        // 
    //  options.c_oflag |= (NL1 | CR1 | FFDLY);


    tcsetattr(intFd, TCSANOW, &options);

    return intFd;
}
```

and this is the sample where I check my serial number:

```
int  serial=0;
    ioctl(intFd, TIOCMGET, &serial);
    //for ubuntu 7.04 and 10.04
        if(serial==16390 || serial==16422 || serial==16454 || serial==16486){//no connection with serial port
```

i checked my program many times and serial is 16486 every times and it means I have no connection with serial port , I checked my serial cable and it was ok? so how can I Solve my problem?

Comment: Just for your information, the result from the `TIOCMGET` IOCTL is a *bitfield*, so don't check values, check *bits*.

Comment: You have RTS/CTS enabled. Do you also have the physical wires to support that?

Comment: what you mean exactly ? I use serial port with 9 pin so i have RTS/CTS

Comment: well which bits should be checked in serial?is there any refrence to infom me about this? @Joachim Pileborg

Comment: Normally, serial uses only 3 wires: RX, TX and GND. If you want to use RTS/CTS, you'll also need to have these wired. I don't know which pins, but it'd be easy to find it online. Also, the device you are communicating with should support it.

Comment: @Unix2000 See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty_ioctl.4.html#EXAMPLE for details of the constants for `TIOCMGET`